# Qt application icon not showing properly

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a **Qt application** on **OS X** which uses an **Application Icon**.

In my `.pro` file I have included the following statement:

```
macx: ICON = MyLogo.icns
```

When I build my application through **Qt Creator**, the **MyApplication.app** file has the defined icon, but if I try to manually build it using the following script:

```
SOURCE_DIR="/Users/user/QtProjects/MyApplication"
DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
BUILD_DIR="${SOURCE_DIR}/../Builds/${DATE}"
mkdir -p $BUILD_DIR
cd $BUILD_DIR
qmake "${SOURCE_DIR}/MyApplication.pro" -r -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=x86_64
make -C $BUILD_DIR
macdeployqt "${BUILD_DIR}/MyApplication.app" -dmg
```

the application is successfully built, but the application icon is not shown, it uses a default icon from **OS X**.

For some reason, when I open the `MyApplication.app/Contents`, the `Info.plist` is not there (when building it manually).

Any idea?

**Note**: I'm trying to manually build it because I need to perform some previous and post steps.

Comment: Try to delete precedent compilation files created and recompile again from scratch

Comment: @Dardanboy I have no previous compilation files.